# Count wikipedia results

Tags: count, wikipedia, limits, wikipedia-api

I'd like to get the number of Wikipedia pages matching a condition.
e.g.

- "house" --> 1,200 pages
- "man" --> 13,000 pages
- "university college" --> 360 pages

Among many other ways, I can do this by indexing Wikipedia with Lucene, but that's pretty time consuming.

Is there a way to perform this type of query on the [Media Wiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API)?

What is the query limit on the Wikipedia API?

Cheers,
Mulone

Comment: I don't think Wikipedia will let you do a full-content search on *every single article*. That will be ridiculously costly in terms of both resources and time. You can search titles, however: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=man&limit=100&format=jsonfm

Comment: There are at least 99,000 articles and perhaps 488,000 with the word (or perhaps partword) [house](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=50&offset=99000&redirs=1&profile=default&search=house)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`list=search`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aSearch) query.  For example:

- ["house"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srnamespace=0&srsearch=house&srinfo=totalhits&srlimit=1&srprop=)
- ["man"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srnamespace=0&srsearch=man&srinfo=totalhits&srlimit=1&srprop=)
- ["university college"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srnamespace=0&srsearch=%22university+college%22&srinfo=totalhits&srlimit=1&srprop=)

(Since you said you're only interested in the number of matching pages, I included `srlimit=1`and `srprop=` in the query to minimize the extra information returned.  Apparently there's no way to keep the API from returning at least the title of the first match, though; `srlimit=0` just gives an error message.)

As for query limits, there are [limits on the number of results per query](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aLists#Limits), but I don't think MediaWiki enforces any hard limits on the *rate* at which you query the API.  MediaWiki does limit editing rates, but I don't think any such limits are currently applied for searching.

I believe the recommendation is that you run your queries serially — that is, wait for the previous query to finish before sending the next one.  This provides a sort of automatic rate limiting, since if the servers are busy, your queries will take longer to complete.  If you want to play nice, you could also include a [`maxlag` parameter](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMaxlag_parameter) in your queries (preferably with [exponential backoff](http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2011/05/26/cloud-lesson-learned-exponential-backoff.aspx) if it fails); the maxlag mechanism is really designed more for automatic *edits* than for searching, but it does at least ensure that your code will not hit Wikimedia's server at times when they're particularly overloaded.

Also, if you want to do a *lot* of these kinds of queries, you might want to consider downloading a [Wikipedia database dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) and either indexing it yourself (as you mentioned in your question) or just reading it in a single pass and counting matching pages as you encounter them.